# Sending JSON through API as a Post request in Node and displaying BLOB data in console

Tags: node.js, rest, post, blob, filesaver.js

I have a python flask server running and its api is exposed. It is being used for converting json to excel file. I need to pass json through node code to that api and get back the response which would be a blob and save as a excel file locally. My first step is to display the blob object in console but I am getting a lot of data in console which is irrelevant. Here is my nodejs code

```
const request = require('request');
jsonobj={...} //a big json not displaying here
    request(
  {
  method:'post',
  url:'http://127.0.0.1:8095/excel/download',
    form: jsonobj,
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json"
},
  json: true,
}, function (error, response, body) {
  //Print the Response
  console.log(body);
});
```

The body is displaying a lot of data, I only need to display the excel blob

Comment: Can you please post result of this  console.log(body);

Comment: Wait I'll edit it in the question.

Comment: Then try console.log(body.data);

Comment: I get undefined with console.log(body.data)

Comment: When I do console.log(response.statusCode) I get 500

Comment: Then kindly post result of console.log(body), with this I cannot help.

Comment: In postman when I post the same json I get status code as 200

Comment: If you are getting 500 error then there is some issue with http://127.0.0.1:8095/excel/download file. Kindly check it.

Comment: I am getting this in terminal where I am running python code - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: When I am trying in postman I am getting a status code as 200, so there is mistake with node code.

Comment: I changed form to body and it is resolved but I still need to save blob as a  excel file locally.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I changed form to body in request and it resolved. Here is the code but I still need to convert blob object and save as an excel file locally. -

```
method:'post',
  url:'http://127.0.0.1:8095/excel/download',
    body: jsonobj, //changed form to body here
  headers: {
    "content-type": "application/json"
```